# KML popup balloon editing and clean-up

Tags: gis, kml, google-earth

I have a .kml that I generated from Google Earth with the "Save As" function

this is the file https://pastebin.com/LECsyh9t

when I click on it on GE for desktop it gives me these informations:

[image]

how could I remove that table from the popup while leaving only the title?

I tried deleting the whole "extendedData" section but it removes both, actually it removes the popup at all, which is inconvenient

Answer (score 0):

Add a description field to the placemark in your KML and the extended data will not be displayed. If a placemark has a description element then the extended data will not be visible.

A Placemark with both a description and extended data will only show the title and description in the popup when clicked in Google Earth.